# Newsletter latex template or example

Tags: templates, examples

I thought I had a bright idea when I decided I would write a monthly newsletter in latex.

I use org-mode and emacs as my personal information management system, so it is easy for me to generate latex documents from my data.

The only thing I need is a good newsletter template. There should be lots of them. Right?

What I want is this:http://www.epd.de/sites/default/files/pdf/epd-Ost-Wochenspiegel_2011_35.pdf which is a "tex" newsletter by Stephan Lehmke created with OpenScape

I like the navigation feature in the top and in the right margin. Also over all it looks very professional.

The templates that I have found are not as good. For example:
http://www.latextemplates.com/cat/newsletters

Does anyone have a good example of a latex newsletter with navigation features? Or can anyone point me in the direction of what I need to do to create one and how much effort it would be. I have not used latex now for the last 10 years after graduating from University...

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) On this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are either "off topic", "too broad", or "unclear". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

Comment: May be this one is related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13770/1952

Comment: You might take a look at newspaper.sty -- it is of recent vintage and looks capable. There is also newsletr.tex, but that, while also very clever and capable, uses plain TeX -- too bad as it is also very useful. Moreover, for support, `newsletr.tex` has only a (very extensive) `ReadMe file`. At one time I did LaTeXify (with reasonable success) a part of `newsletr` that outputs 2-up imposed booklets without extra software -- now **that** is *really* clever.

Comment: This is not the style you want, but the Italian magazine *Il Covile* is very attractive and seems to be made with TeX.  See the article on pages 3–4 of http://www.ilcovile.it/scritti/COVILE_542.pdf

Comment: Related: [Magazine template?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/283037)

Comment: Could you provide a minimal example please? I would love to have the epd layout too :-)

Comment: I asked for help for the header: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/301024/how-do-i-create-a-header-with-tikz-boxed-chapter-references ... hopefully a kind person will help us :-)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could build upon http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/erdc.

Personally, I like the IEEE magazine style, but the template doesn't appear to be in the public domain.