# Magazine template?

Tags: templates

Does anybody know where I can find [this kind](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nxrmw090p196x13/magazine.pdf?dl=0) of template for magazine:

[image]

Or something similar? (not exactly the same, but similar design?) I have checked many websites, but haven't found anything.

Comment: I'm not sure there is something specific for that, but you could use Tikz.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer - I was just wondering whether anybody has already used / developed such a template and made it available for other users... But I'm afraid I'll have to start from scratch. Thanks anyway!

Comment: To close voters: I think this issue deserves some discussion on meta. http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/6420/2693

Comment: The flowfram package was intended for newsletters.

Answer (score 44):

You do not specify the minimum (similar?) requirements of your desired magazine layout, but in general, such complex and inconsistent layouts are more suitable for desktop publishing software as Scribus or InDesign.

Said that, there are the [paperTeX](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/papertex) document class:

[image: mwe]

There also a [newspaper](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/newspaper) package to produce a similar layout to the *New York Times*:

[image: mew]

And even the [newsletr](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/newsletr) macros in plain TeX for this purpose:

[image: mwe]

Finally, [flowfram](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/flowfram) package allow you to design your own layout. See [Three-columns text with figures of 2\columnwidth](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70175/three-columns-text-with-figures-of-2-columnwidth) for more information:

[image: flowframdemo]

Of course, there are also others packages as 
[cuted](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/cuted) and
[cutwin](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/cuted) that can help in text shapes in differrent ways, as well as  many others to obtain magazine-like effects (backgrounds, etc.) but this is a too broad subject.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful comments. Indeed, I wasn't very precise when defining "similar" - what I meant was a similar structure, that is, a front page with a title and a background image, followed by a sort of "in this issue" page (references to the articles) and with the "magazine-like" formatted articles after. From your suggestions, I believe that what I had in my mind is a combination of all the sources you provided, so thanks again for your very helpful indications.

Comment: @abaz You are welcome. Then, see also in CTAN  [wallpaper](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/wallpaper)  package and the topics [titlepage](https://www.ctan.org/topic/titlepage)  and [toc-etc](https://www.ctan.org/topic/toc-etc). Also in this site there are a lot of questions about cover pages and custom table of contents with many examples.

Comment: @abaz: Then please edit your question.

Comment: **background** is more flexible than **wallpaper** but **wallpaper** is easier. @abaz Note that combining all of these is not straightforward. If you insist on using LaTeX, the best thing might be to create each page as a separate document and then combine the PDFs in a single file.