# How do I separate blocks of different height multicolumns and have separate columns below one another?

Tags: multicol, multirow, multicolumn, newspaper

I am trying to start a small newspaper, and have tried doing it in Latex.

So far I've made use of the helpful newspaper package for headline and byline macros, as well as the title creation.

Additionally, I've experimented with `multicols`, `graphicx`, and `picinpar` packages, but they do not suffice.

The following is quite a nasty, but comprehensive example of the kinds of things I would like to do:

[image: NYTimes JP Surrender Front Page]

I have no need for the more complicated text shapes present (like columns folding over another partially). But how would one have related paragraphs in their own two columns or more below other columns of text. As opposed to the way `multicols` or `multicols*` function, having paragraph text keep going until the page height is filled?

Additionally how would one have a single paragraph span the width of two columns as one?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Magazine template?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/283037/magazine-template)

Comment: I think that [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/283119/11604) is useful also for your question.

Comment: no, i've looked at all those options and they do something very specific that I don't need. I need more control over columns.

Comment: To reopen I think that we need a more precise question and a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) showing what you have tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**flowframe**

Have a look at Nicola Talbot’s package [flowframe](http://ctan.org/pkg/flowfram). She has even made a drawing program [jpgfdraw](http://ctan.org/pkg/jpgfdraw), which can be used to construct `flowframe`-pages. `flowframe` can link text between different frame (cf. your next to last question)

**textpos**

If this is not suitable, you may try to build up the page using the package [textpos](http://ctan.org/pkg/textpos). This is a very advanced package, and I am pretty sure that you will be able to typeset a newspaper with it. You can build a page by stacking textboxes around. Inside the textboxes, you may use multicol:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{textpos}
\TPGrid[40mm,20mm]{10}{5}

\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{textblock*}{5cm}(4cm,4cm)
\begin{multicols}{2}

Mul­ti­col de­fines a mul­ti­cols en­vi­ron­ment which type­sets text in mul­ti­ple columns (up to a max­i­mum of 10), and (by de­fault) bal­ances the end of each column at the end of the en­vi­ron­ment. The pack­age en­ables you to switch be­tween any (per­mit­ted) num­ber of columns at will: there is no im­posed "clear page" op­er­a­tion, as there is in un­adorned LaTeX at a switch be­tween onecol­umn and twocol­umn sec­tions. The mul­ti­col­umn en­vi­ron­ment can also be used in­side a box, thus al­low­ing mul­ti­columned in­sets in text.

Mul­ti­col patches the out­put rou­tine, and may clash with other pack­ages that do the same (e.g., longtable); fur­ther­more, there is no pro­vi­sion for sin­gle col­umn floats in­side a mul­ti­col­umn en­vi­ron­ment, so fig­ures and ta­bles must be coded in-line (us­ing, for ex­am­ple, the H mod­i­fier of the float pack­age).

The pack­age is part of the la­tex-tools bun­dle in the LaTeX re­quired dis­tri­bu­tion. 

\end{multicols}
\end{textblock*}

\end{document}
```

**minipage**

A third solution is to build the page using minipages with multicol inside:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{minipage}[b]{5cm}
\raggedleft
\begin{multicols}{2}

Mul­ti­col de­fines a mul­ti­cols en­vi­ron­ment which type­sets text in mul­ti­ple columns (up to a max­i­mum of 10), and (by de­fault) bal­ances the end of each column at the end of the en­vi­ron­ment. The pack­age en­ables you to switch be­tween any (per­mit­ted) num­ber of columns at will: there is no im­posed "clear page" op­er­a­tion, as there is in un­adorned LaTeX at a switch be­tween onecol­umn and twocol­umn sec­tions. The mul­ti­col­umn en­vi­ron­ment can also be used in­side a box, thus al­low­ing mul­ti­columned in­sets in text.

Mul­ti­col patches the out­put rou­tine, and may clash with other pack­ages that do the same (e.g., longtable); fur­ther­more, there is no pro­vi­sion for sin­gle col­umn floats in­side a mul­ti­col­umn en­vi­ron­ment, so fig­ures and ta­bles must be coded in-line (us­ing, for ex­am­ple, the H mod­i­fier of the float pack­age).

The pack­age is part of the la­tex-tools bun­dle in the LaTeX re­quired dis­tri­bu­tion. 

\end{multicols}
\end{minipage}\strut

\end{document}
```

That said, LaTex is not the best solution for typesetting newspapers.

Comment: I think Latex is quite a good solution for formatting newspapers, as the results I have so far look really good, better than most manually typeset in Quark or Adobe papers I've seen. I would just like to have a few more tools in my toolbox to do some more advanced typesetting relevant to newspaper layout.

Comment: @G.David I have never produced a newspaper, so my experience with newspaper software is nil. My impression was that it is easier to compose a newspaper page with software with graphical interface and support for register typesetting and ‘disruptive’ columns.