# Automatically add \begin{multicols}{N} to chapters styled with \titleformat

Tags: titlesec, multicol

I'm trying to create a 3 column book layout. So far the only way I've figured out to get 3 columns is to use the venerable `multicol` package, which works nicely. Using the answer from this question [Automatically add \begin{multicols}{N} to chapters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/450051/2693) I'm attempting to use `etoolbox` to automatically insert the `\begin` `\end` `multicols` whenever I type `\chapter`; however, this breaks when styling chapters using `titlesec`.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{titlesec}          % Customize chapters and sections
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

% Automatically wrap \chapter with \begin and \end multicols
\newif\iffirst
\makeatletter
\appto{\mainmatter}
{\firsttrue
\preto{\chapter}{\iffirst\firstfalse\else\end{multicols*}\fi}
\preto{\enddocument}{\end{multicols*}}
\apptocmd{\@makechapterhead}{\begin{multicols*}{3}}{}{}
\apptocmd{\@makeschapterhead}{\begin{multicols*}{3}}{}{}
}
\makeatother

% Format chapter heading
\titleformat
    {\chapter} % command
    [display]  % shape
    {\LARGE} % format
    {} % label 
    {-1.75cm} % horizontal separation between label and title body
    {Chapter \thechapter. \enspace \vspace{0cm}} % before-code
    [] % after-code

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\chapter{A chapter}
\kant
\chapter{A chapter}
\kant
\chapter{A chapter}
\kant
\end{document}
```

Latex complains about a `! Argument of \begin has an extra }.` What's the best way to make this work?

Answer (score 5):

I'd do it differently:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{titlesec}          % Customize chapters and sections
\usepackage{xparse}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}

% Automatically wrap \chapter with \begin and \end multicols

\let\latexchapter\chapter
\newif\iffirst
\appto\mainmatter{\sloppy\global\firsttrue\let\chapter\zendelchapter}
\raggedbottom

\NewDocumentCommand{\zendelchapter}{sO{#3}m}{%
  \iffirst\global\firstfalse\else\end{multicols*}\fi
  \begin{multicols*}{3}[%
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}{\latexchapter*{#3}}{\latexchapter[#2]{#3}}%
  ]
}
\AtEndDocument{\end{multicols*}}

% Format chapter heading
\titleformat
    {\chapter} % command
    [display]  % shape
    {\LARGE} % format
    {} % label 
    {-1.75cm} % horizontal separation between label and title body
    {Chapter \thechapter.\quad} % before-code
    [] % after-code
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{50pt}{51.7pt}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\chapter{A chapter}
\kant
\chapter{A chapter}
\kant
\chapter{A chapter}
\kant
\end{document}
```

The strange `51.7pt` has been computed by trial and error, in order to ensure an integral number of lines in the chapter pages.

For older TeX distribution, an error

```
! Illegal parameter number in definition of \zendelchapter
```

can be solved by replacing the given definition of `\zendelchapter` with

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\zendelchapter}{som}{%
  \iffirst\global\firstfalse\else\end{multicols*}\fi
  \begin{multicols*}{3}[%
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}
     {%
      \latexchapter*{#3}%
     }
     {%
      \IfNoValueTF{#2}
       {%
        \latexchapter{#3}%
       }%
       {%
        \latexchapter[#2]{#3}%
       }%
     }%
  ]
}
```

Comment: Both latex and lualatex report errors when trying to compile this:

` ~ > lualatex example.tex`
...
`! You can't use macro parameter character # in horizontal mode.`
`<argument> \numberline {1}##`
`                 ######3`

Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: @Zendel No error for me. Unfortunately the version of TeX Live provided by Ubuntu lags behind the current one, so you have a very outdated TeX system. I added a workaround.

Comment: Thanks, this works in my version of latex. I'm slowly getting more confident with it -- it's just been a low priority. This is very helpful.