# Newspaper layout - images covering 2 out of 5 columns

Tags: floats, multicol

I'm trying to format my Latex document like a newspaper page. It should roughly have the same layout as shown in the image here: https://www.landscape.net.au/leader-newspapers-feature-plant-with-style/

So I'm using a4paper, landscape mode and the multicol package with 5 columns. But getting images and other kinds of figures like tables and code listings to float properly appears to be insanely hard due to lots of Latex wrinkles. Floats apparently doesn't work at all with multicol and what I've tried as workarounds, like using minipages doesn't work either both because the minipage covers the running text and because I can't put it in the top right corner.

But looking at slide 106 in this German tutorial, clearly getting the layout I want is doable! http://www.deesaster.org/latex/LaTeX-Magazinerstellung-Handout.pdf But how?

Comment: Have you looked at this example:  [Magazine template?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/283119/22413)

Comment: I've looked at flowfram and it almost works but is kind of wonky. Long words aren't hyphenated properly so instead they continue into neighboring columns.

Comment: @BjörnLindqvist: If you're setting things like a newspaper, then you should use a `\raggedright` setting and possibly include [`microtype`](//ctan.org/pkg/microtype).

Comment: @Werner why? Then the right side of the columns does not align.

Comment: Also disagree with the duplication mark since I tried the accepted answer of that question and it doesn't work.

Comment: @BjörnLindqvist: 5 columns on a regular sheet of paper sounds like very narrow columns, hence my suggestion. Moreover, you'll notice a `\raggedright` view in the image *you* provided as a sample. [`ragged2e`](//ctan.org/pkg/ragged2e) provides some improved hyphenation, if that helps.