# Placing text exactly on a page

Tags: formatting

One thing that has been bothering me in the last 2 months since I started using LaTeX is the inability to place text EXACTLY where I want it on a page

Advice in this regard would be welcome

EDIT:
Using the code by @Fran for `textpos` why is there an overlap of the text

Why is the `\cleardoublepage` not put the second code output on a separate new page

```
     \documentclass{article}

     \usepackage[absolute]{textpos}
     \usepackage{lipsum}
     \begin{document}
     \setlength{\TPHorizModule}{30mm}
     \setlength{\TPVertModule}{\TPHorizModule}
     \textblockorigin{10mm}{10mm} % start everything near the top-left corner
     \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
     \begin{textblock}{3}(0,0)
     This block is 3 modules wide,  and is placed with its top left corner
     at the ‘origin’ on the page. Note that the length of the block is not
     specified in the arguments -- the box will be as long as necessary to
     accomodate the text inside it. You need to examine the output of the
     text to adjust the positioning of the blocks on the page.
     \end{textblock}

     \begin{textblock}{2}(2,1)
     \textblocklabel{block two}
     Here is another, slightly narrower, block, at position (2,1) on the page.
     \end{textblock}

     \begin{textblock}{3}[0.5,0.5](2,3)
     This block is at position (2,3), but because the optional argument

     [0.5,0.5] has been given, it is the centre of the block which is
     located at that point, rather than the top-left corner.
     \end{textblock}
    \cleardoublepage
    ------------------------------------
    \setlength{\TPHorizModule}{1cm}
    \setlength{\TPVertModule}{\TPHorizModule}
    \textblockorigin{10mm}{10mm} 
    \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

    \begin{textblock}{3}(0,0)\lipsum[1][1-3]\end{textblock}
    \begin{textblock}{3}(3.2,3)\lipsum[1][4-5]\end{textblock}
    \begin{textblock}{3}(5.6,4.7)\lipsum[1][6-9]\end{textblock}
    \begin{textblock}{6}(6.5,8.5)\lipsum[1][9-14]\end{textblock}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Kindly advise

Comment: Welcome to tex.stackexchange! Please be more specific: what kind of text, where on the page... Otherwise, make a minimal working example (MWE) -- take a look [here](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) -- telling us what it looks like what you want to change -- i.e., how you want it to look like.

Comment: Use tikz or tikzpagenodes with [remember picture, overlay] and (current page) etc. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/273868/size-and-position-of-boxes-in-title-page/273885?s=2|2.0686#273885  You might also look at flowfram

Comment: It is no problem placing text or other element at exact position. Just use the correct commands and/or packages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}
\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{1cm}
\setlength{\TPVertModule}{\TPHorizModule}
\textblockorigin{10mm}{10mm} 
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}
\begin{textblock}{3}(0,0)\lipsum[1][1-3]\end{textblock}
\begin{textblock}{3}(3.2,3)\lipsum[1][4-5]\end{textblock}
\begin{textblock}{3}(5.6,4.7)\lipsum[1][6-9]\end{textblock}
\begin{textblock}{6}(6.5,8.5)\lipsum[1][9-14]\end{textblock}
\end{document}
```

Comment: please see edit above in main question--why the overlap --something I missed?

Comment: @jsbibra Because in`\begin{textblock}{z}(x,y)` each box is in the `(x,y)` position, where `x` and `y` are (in this case) centimeters, and each box will have a width of `{z}` cm, and this will be yes or yes, irrespectively of any other `textblock` environment or whatever. Avoid overlap is your responsibility, tuning x, y and z accordingly. That is,  `texpos` does just what you asked: "*place text EXACTLY where I want it*", isn't it?

Comment: @jsbibra The optional parameter `[r,t]` move the original x,y position to the right and top direction (if the number is positive), but this only add confusion to your example, the problem of overlapping is that `texpos` does not take care of this, beside use  `[absolute]` (the package option) or relative positions. This is against its purpose. Run `texdoc texpos` for more information.

Comment: You may want to look at the `flowfram` package if you want to do a layout like a magazine or newspaper.

Comment: @Cicada [I know](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/283119/11604), but the question was not about newpapers layouts.